# How to set papersize to legal in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, resize, size

Im trying to print the contents of my datagridview to a legal or long size bond paper but i can't find the code to make the paper in preview dialog to long. Here is my code for print preview and print:

```
Private Sub btnPreview_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPreview.Click
    Dim strcon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\NMGInventory\NMGInventory\Supplies.mdb")
    Try
        strcon.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "SELECT * From [product info]"
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strcon)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("product info")
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        print.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        .
        preview.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
        preview.Document = print
        preview.Show()

        AddHandler print.PrintPage, AddressOf print_PrintPage
        strcon.Close()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub print_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim ColumnCount As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
    Dim RowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount

    Dim CellTopPos As Integer = print.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top

    For Row = 0 To RowCount - 1

        Dim CellLeftPos As Integer = print.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
        Dim CellRightPos As Integer = print.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right
        For Cell = 0 To ColumnCount - 1

            Dim CellValue As String = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Value.ToString()
            Dim CellWidth = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Width + 50
            Dim CellHeight = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Height

            Dim CellWidth1 = DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(Cell).Size.Width + -30

            Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CellValue, New Font("Century Gothic", 10), Brush, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)
            CellLeftPos += CellWidth
        Next

        CellTopPos += DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Size.Height
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following setting

```
Dim xCustomSize As New PaperSize("Legal", 850, 1400)

        Me.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = xCustomSize
```